# Balls into bins with left and right bins always empty

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, monte-carlo, balls-in-bins

N balls are sequentially and randomly allocated into M bins arranged in a circle. If a bin receives a ball, its left and right bins cannot receive any ball and are always set to be empty (new coming balls are discarded). What is the expected number of occupied bins at last?

From my simulation of N=M=100, the expected number is 36, but I want to know if it can be formulated mathematically. When N=M=4, simulation gives a value around 1.576.

Background: This is a quantitative interview question I am trying to solve. This question is an extension of the original balls-into-bins problem, which adds the dependency to the neighbour boxes by introducing a special constraint.

Additional Explanation: The original balls-into-bins question only says N balls are randomly allocated into M bins. Please calculate the expected number of non-empty bins. The answer is
$$
M\left (1-\left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^N \right )
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: (as hinted by Henry) The solution in its current form only gives a lower bound.

Denote by $A_i$ the Bernoulli variable, which is equal to one if $i$-th bin is non-empty after throwing $N$ balls. Then, the expected value of the total number of non-empty bins $A$ is equal to
$$ \mathbb{E}[A] = \sum_{i=1}^M \mathbb{E}[A_i]. $$
Since the $A_i$'s are Bernoulli variables, their expected value is $\mathbb{E}[A_i] = P(A_i = 1)$. Since $A_i$ is equal to one if it is selected at some $j$-th throw and none of its neighbors were selected before, we have
\begin{align*}
P(A_i=1) \geq \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{M} \left(\frac{M-3}{M}\right)^{j-1} = \frac1M \frac{1-(1-(3/M))^N}{3/M} = \frac{1-(1-(3/M))^N}{3}.
\end{align*}
Note that this is only a lower bound, since the neighbors might be selected, but not filled, if one of *their* neighbors has been selected before. And thus
$$ \mathbb{E}[A] \geq M \frac{1-(1-(3/M))^N}{3} $$
You can either compute this exactly or approximate the numerator for $M=N=100$ with $1-\mathrm{e}^{-3}$, which gives $\mathbb{E}[A] \geq 31.7$.

Comment: For $M=4, N=4$, I am getting $\frac{101}{64}$ rather than what looks like $\frac{85}{64}$ from your expression

Comment: @Henry: You are right. I have overseen that even if one hits the neighbors, these balls might not be accepted, due to their neighbors being occupied. I am not sure, how to correct the above solution due to these annoying dependencies. Feel free to add your correct solution.

Comment: From my simulation, I also get 1.576 for N=M=4. BTW, I don't know what I should add to make this question open again. It always says please provide additional context.

Comment: @YirunZhang your simulation is consistent with my exact result of $\frac{101}{64} = 1.578125$

Comment: @Henry The question is open again. Please feel free to post your answer!

Comment: I do not have an answer - I only calculated one case

Comment: That case is for $M=4$ where I seem to get $2 - \left(\frac34\right)^{N-1}$.  The case of $M=5$ should not be much more complicated, without checking perhaps $2 - \left(\frac35\right)^{N-1}$, but $M=6$ might be and then it gets worse